# POI Copy Images do not resize

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with the POI API to copy many Excel Workbooks into 1 large Excel Workbook. For one of my requirements there are images that are placed and sized specifically in the document. I am using the combination of the below code to transfer all of the images necessary. They will only be pictures and ALL of the pictures are found.

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTPositiveSize2D; // only important class you need to know about.

private static void transferShape (XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFSheet newSheet) {
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    for(XSSFShape shape : drawing.getShapes()) {
        if(shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
            XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;
            transferPicture(picture, newSheet);
        }
    }
}

private static void transferPicture(XSSFPicture picture, XSSFSheet newSheet) {
    XSSFPictureData xssfPictureData = picture.getPictureData();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = picture.getPreferredSize();

    int col1 = anchor.getCol1();
    int col2 = anchor.getCol2();
    int row1 = anchor.getRow1();
    int row2 = anchor.getRow2();

    int x1 = anchor.getDx1();
    int x2 = anchor.getDx2();
    int y1 = anchor.getDy1();
    int y2 = anchor.getDy2();

    XSSFWorkbook newWb = newSheet.getWorkbook();
    XSSFCreationHelper newHelper = newWb.getCreationHelper();
    XSSFDrawing newDrawing = newSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor newAnchor = newHelper.createClientAnchor();

    newAnchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

    // Row / Column placement.
    newAnchor.setCol1(col1);
    newAnchor.setCol2(col2);
    newAnchor.setRow1(row1);
    newAnchor.setRow2(row2);

    // Fine touch adjustment along the XY coordinate.
    newAnchor.setDx1(x1);
    newAnchor.setDx2(x2);
    newAnchor.setDy1(y1);
    newAnchor.setDy2(y2);

    double imageX = 0;
    double imageY = 0;

    if(anchor.getSize() != null) {
        newAnchor.setSize(anchor.getSize());
    } else {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        for(int col = col1; col <= col2; col++) {
            width += Math.round(Units.columnWidthToEMU(newSheet.getColumnWidth(col)));
        }

        width -= x1 - x2;

        for(int row = row1; row <= row2; row++) {
            height += Math.round(Units.TwipsToEMU(newSheet.getRow(row).getHeight()));
        }

        height -= y1 - y2;


        CTPositiveSize2D ps2D = CTPositiveSize2D.Factory.newInstance();


        ps2D.setCx((long) 0);
        ps2D.setCy((long) 0);

        newAnchor.setSize(ps2D);
    }

    int newPictureIndex = newWb.addPicture(xssfPictureData.getData(), xssfPictureData.getPictureType());

    XSSFPicture newPicture = newDrawing.createPicture(newAnchor, newPictureIndex);
    newPicture.resize();
}
```

However, the main issue is that the images are not sizing correctly any more. Something happened that broke that functionality. I had to add the following else to work on a new solution.

```
else {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    for(int col = col1; col <= col2; col++) {
        width += Math.round(Units.columnWidthToEMU(newSheet.getColumnWidth(col)));
    }

    width -= x1 - x2;

    for(int row = row1; row <= row2; row++) {
        height += Math.round(Units.TwipsToEMU(newSheet.getRow(row).getHeight()));
    }

    height -= y1 - y2;


    CTPositiveSize2D ps2D = CTPositiveSize2D.Factory.newInstance();


    ps2D.setCx((long) 0);
    ps2D.setCy((long) 0);

    newAnchor.setSize(ps2D);
}
```

Yet... even setting Cx and Cy to 0 nothing is being resized still. I am unsure what is going on.

`newAnchor.setSize(anchor.getSize())` used to work all by itself. Not sure what changed for it to return null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a case of too much code from the API! Basically the size of the image is defined by its location and distance pushed by the `dx` and `dy` variables.

The below functions are the final product and works very well.

```
private static void transferShape (XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFSheet newSheet) {
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    for(XSSFShape shape : drawing.getShapes()) {
        if(shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
            transferPicture(shape, newSheet);
        }
    }
}

private static void transferPicture(XSSFShape shape, XSSFSheet newSheet) {
    XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;

    XSSFPictureData xssfPictureData = picture.getPictureData();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor) shape.getAnchor();

    int col1 = anchor.getCol1();
    int col2 = anchor.getCol2();
    int row1 = anchor.getRow1();
    int row2 = anchor.getRow2();

    int x1 = anchor.getDx1();
    int x2 = anchor.getDx2();
    int y1 = anchor.getDy1();
    int y2 = anchor.getDy2();

    XSSFWorkbook newWb = newSheet.getWorkbook();
    XSSFCreationHelper newHelper = newWb.getCreationHelper();
    XSSFDrawing newDrawing = newSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor newAnchor = newHelper.createClientAnchor();

    // Row / Column placement.
    newAnchor.setCol1(col1);
    newAnchor.setCol2(col2);
    newAnchor.setRow1(row1);
    newAnchor.setRow2(row2);

    // Fine touch adjustment along the XY coordinate.
    newAnchor.setDx1(x1);
    newAnchor.setDx2(x2);
    newAnchor.setDy1(y1);
    newAnchor.setDy2(y2);

    int newPictureIndex = newWb.addPicture(xssfPictureData.getData(), xssfPictureData.getPictureType());

    XSSFPicture newPicture = newDrawing.createPicture(newAnchor, newPictureIndex);
}
```

Hoping this helps someone. This was a really weird problem that I haven't yet found.